# How to get List<MyModel> type in my Controller using partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using for loop in my view which is generating certain partial views. This is my partial view:

```
@model Typical_MVC_Application.Controllers.testPartialModel

Test Partial
<input type="text" name="textprop" value="@Model.text" />
```

Here i am using loop in my main view

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{ 
    @Html.Partial("TestPartial", 
        new Typical_MVC_Application.Controllers.testPartialModel() { textprop = "something 222" })
}
```

Now if I handle data in action like :

```
public ActionResult Index(List<testPartialModel> partialmodeldata /* no data is here*/)
{  }
```

And here is my model:

```
public class testPartialModel
{
     public string textprop { get; set; }
}
```

Generated HTML:

```
Test Partial <input type="text" name="textprop" value="something 222" /> 
Test Partial <input type="text" name="textprop" value="something 222" /> 
Test Partial <input type="text" name="textprop" value="something 222" /> 
Test Partial <input type="text" name="textprop" value="something 222" /> 
Test Partial <input type="text" name="textprop" value="something 222" />
```

How can I get data? I have tried array type, `IEnumerable`, `List`, `List<string>` .. but nothing worked.

Comment: you'll have to look at the HTML on the page.  It needs to conform to MVC's standards to rebuild the model.  Check [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)

Comment: HTML is quite simple : 
Test Partial
<input type="text" name="textprop" value="something 222" />

Test Partial
<input type="text" name="textprop" value="something 222" />

Test Partial
<input type="text" name="textprop" value="something 222" />

Test Partial
<input type="text" name="textprop" value="something 222" />

Test Partial
<input type="text" name="textprop" value="something 222" />

Comment: your approach will work good enough with main view, coz I can pass value of i which is being generated from loop. But how to get this value in partialview, I dont know :(.

Comment: right, so as those are all identical, it won't be able to rebuild your model.  I'm not sure of the solution, but that's your problem

Comment: thanx for your time and suggestion :). Hope somebody will look after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for a for loop to render fields with the right names with indexes, the actual indexed object must be passed:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Foos.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Foos[i])
}
```

This applies to partials, as well. So you'd have to do:

```
@Html.Partial("_Foo", Model.Foos[i])
```

Your problem is that you're creating a new instance of your `testPartialModel` each iteration, and essentially throwing away the context. Razor has no way of knowing what the index should be or even that there should be any sort of prefix at all. There's two solutions to this:

1. Don't create these objects in your view. Instead, use a view model for your view, if you're not already, and add a list property containing these `testPartialInstances` already initialized. Then, you can simply iterate through this list property and render your partial as above with a properly indexed object. This is the preferred solution. Your view should not be responsible for this type of logic.
2. You can technically control the prefix Razor will add to the fields in the partial, by passing your own view data:

   ```
   @Html.Partial("_Foo", fooInstance, new ViewDataDictionary
   {
       TemplateInfo = new System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = string.Format("Foo[{0}]", i) }
   }
   ```

   Razor will then prefix this `HtmlFieldPrefix` value to each field it renders in the partial. However, in your scenario here, this is a band-aid. You should really just improve your code as explained in option #1.

Comment: Yessss.. this is what I was expecting this. I would definitely follow 1st one, but the problem is the application is developed by someone else and there are lot of controls being generated so.. However I haven't tried 2nd option yet but I know it will work as expected. thanx.